# JQuery .fadeToggle() not working properly: Automatically fades out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tree label', function(e) {
  $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree">
  <li class="has">
    <label class="container">ROOT<span class="total">(12) </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="domain[]" value="ROOT">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label></ul>

<ul style="display: none;">
  <li><label class="container">CHILD<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="CHILD"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

When I click the first label it should `fadeToggle` the next `ul`. But as soon as it fades in it fades out automatically.

Can anyone please let me know where is the issue? Is HTML format is incorrect?

Comment: Tried your code in codepen and it does work as expected.

Comment: @the.marolie can you share pen link please?

Comment: https://codepen.io/akshithMarolie/pen/BaOGmQa

Comment: @the.marolie It is reproducible in your pen also.

Answer (score 0):

Your html markup is wrong. You haven't closed the first `ul`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tree label', function(e) {
  $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree">
  <li class="has">
    <label class="container">ROOT<span class="total">(12) </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="domain[]" value="ROOT">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li><label class="container">CHILD<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="CHILD"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

It does not fade out for me.  Here's a screenshot

[image: ss]

Comment: It is reproducible in your code snippet also. Try running it.

Comment: It does not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your last edit added a `</li></ul>` but they are misplaced - the `</ul>` is not required at all, and the `<li>` should be after the first checkbox.  I've removed them in the code below.

The code snippet does not display the problem you describe - the `CHILD` is not displayed at all.  That's because `.next()` selects [the next *sibling*](https://api.jquery.com/next/).  Sibling means an element at the same level in the DOM tree, but you're looking for siblings of your `<label>`.  If you format the HTML correctly it is easier to see:

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li class="has">
        <label class="container">ROOT
            <span class="total">(12)</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="domain[]" value="ROOT">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <!-- This is where any siblings of $('.tree label') would be -->
    </li> <!-- This /li is missing from your HTML -->
</ul>
```

If you have a series of these on the page, and the logic is that you really want the next one down, you could use `.closest()` to find the parent `ul` of the event click, and then use `.next()` to get the following `ul`.  Like so:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tree label', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('ul').next('ul').fadeToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree">
    <li class="has">
        <label class="container">ROOT
            <span class="total">(12)</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="domain[]" value="ROOT">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul style="display: none;">
    <li>
        <label class="container">CHILD
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="CHILD">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```